# How to track which Like button widget triggered Event.Subscribe edge.create callback?

Tags: facebook, callback, facebook-like

Is there any way to track yet which button was clicked? I know you can use href and widget but they are both pretty much useless if the URL is the same in multiple buttons.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    alert('You liked ' + href + widget);
});
```

All this does is return the URL (which is completely useless for figuring out which button was clicked if you have more than one on the page) and all the widget variable returns is [object][object]

Can someone give me more information on the widget variable and how it can be used?

This is really getting annoying, Google and Twitter both make this very simple witht heir APIs why does facebook refuse to let people know what button was clicked?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you *can* use the `widget` parameter to tell which Like button was clicked. Which I did not know, since it's [not documented](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) as far as I can tell (except in [this blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/446/)).

In your callback, instead of doing an `alert(widget)` try a `console.log(widget)`. This will show you (in a JavaScript console, like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)), all of the information in the object (which is much more useful than just `[object]`).

There are probably a couple of ways to do this, but one way I just tried was to add an ID to my Like button, like so:

```
<fb:like id="myButtonOne" href="http://testurl.com"></fb:like>
```

Then, in the callback, look at the `widget.dom.id` property to see if it has my ID:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
  //console.log(widget); // looks inside the widget object, for testing
  alert(widget.dom.id);
});
```

You should get a popup alert which says "myButtonOne". I you give each button a unique ID, you can now tell in the `edge.create` callback which button was clicked on (even if they have the same URL/href)!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `widget` parameter to get the HTML element of the like button which triggered the event.

This new parameter was recently added to the official documentation.
Take a look here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/